# Div is not hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to hide this div using JQuery.

```
<div id="nbar" style="background-color: #f7f7f7; box-shadow: 0 0 1px lightgray; margin-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 0; width: 100%; margin-top: 5px" class="search-navbar collapse navbar-collapse font-xs">
            <ul class="no-margin nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#" id="ccb">Computer Code</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="nameb">Name</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="experienceb">Experience</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="winsb">No of Win Cases</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="totalb">Total Cases</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="tlsrankb">TLS Rank</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!---End of no-margin nav navbar-nav--->
        </div>
```

using this in ready

```
    function SearchLawyers(SearchText) {

            var url1 = "LawyerData/SearchLawyer/?pTextToSearch=" + SearchText;
            MyWebApp.Gl

obals.MakeAjaxCall("GET", url1, "{}", function (result) {
            if (result.success === true) {
                console.log(result);

                window.globala = result.data;
                debugger;

                if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(window.globala.LawyerList)) {
                    window.isFind = false;
                    $("#nbar").css({ 'display': 'none' });
                    $("#nbar").hide();
                    $(".no-margin nav navbar-nav").hide();
                    $("#Records").html("<h1>No Results Found...!!!<h1>");
                }
                else {
                    window.isFind = true;

                    DisplayLawyerData(result.data);
                    }
            } else {
                MyWebApp.UI.showRoasterMessage(result.error, Enums.MessageType.Error);
            }
        }, function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            MyWebApp.UI.showRoasterMessage('A problem has occurred while getting Lawyers: "' + thrownError + '". Please try again.', Enums.MessageType.Error);
        });

    }
```

but its not working. jquery executes successfully and not showing any error but div is still in on the page. No record found shows but div also visible

Comment: you might be hiding before element is added to DOM

Comment: its working here https://jsfiddle.net/82rpsyhk/

Comment: can you put your full javascript code or function so i can evaluate?

Comment: in which event did you write the above code?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are hiding the `div` before it actually render to the page. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#nbar").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//in document ready event

$('#nbar').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nbar" style="background-color: #f7f7f7; box-shadow: 0 0 1px lightgray; margin-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 0; width: 100%; margin-top: 5px" class="search-navbar collapse navbar-collapse font-xs">
            <ul class="no-margin nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#" id="ccb">Computer Code</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="nameb">Name</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="experienceb">Experience</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="winsb">No of Win Cases</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="totalb">Total Cases</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="tlsrankb">TLS Rank</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!---End of no-margin nav navbar-nav--->
        </div>
```

Comment: It should work. Can you put the code which is not working in fiddle?

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
      
        MyWebApp.UI.lawyerlist.readyMain( );
    });

Comment: Looks like the issue could be somewhere else in your code. Is this condition  -> if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(window.globala.LawyerList)) { is passing?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is event based you need to hide on some event like on Window load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#nbar").hide();
});
```

**Or**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $("#nbar").css({'display':'none'});
    });
```

Comment: did you check your jquery is working or not?
Add alert on window ready.
if your jquery alert woks then try to hide by using css(the second method)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nbar").hide();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/82rpsyhk/1/